# Can an ellipse have integer values for perimeter and area?

Tags: sequences-and-series, conic-sections, inverse-function, elliptic-integrals

Is it possible to find an ellipse whose perimeter and area are integer values? I guess that such ellipse doesn't exist, but I haven't fully proved that.

Obviously if both the semiaxes are algebraic, the area is ruled out, but the same is for the perimeter, as stated [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149686/is-the-perimeter-of-an-ellipse-with-integer-axes-irrational).

The ellipse's perimeter is $ 4aE(e) $, where $a$ is the major semiaxis, the function $ E(x) $ is the [complete elliptic integral of second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html), and $ 0 < e < 1 $ is the eccentricity defined as $ e = \sqrt{1- \frac {b^2}{a^2}} $ with $ b $ as the minor semiaxis

So to find an integer value for the perimeter, I need the inverse function of $ E(x) $, but contrary to the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, there is no known special function for that, but just series ([here](https://analyticphysics.com/Special%20Functions/Inverse%20Elliptic%20Integrals%20of%20the%20First%20and%20Second%20Kinds.htm) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357492/inverse-of-the-incomplete-elliptic-integral-of-the-second-kind) some references), so, because I wanted a closed form, ising the results of this theorem due to [Selberg and Chowla](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chowla%E2%80%93Selberg_formula), if k is a singular modulus then $ E(k) $ can be evaluated in closed form in terms of $ π $ and values of Gamma function at rational points ([here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) some examples).
So, if the perimeter is a positive integer $ n $ then $4aE(e) = n \Rightarrow a = \frac {n}{4E(e)} $

$ b = \sqrt{a^2(1-e^2)}  = \sqrt{\frac{(1-e^2)n^2}{(4E(e))^2}} $

and the area is $ A = πab = \frac{π\sqrt{(1-e^2)}n^2}{(4E(e))^2} $

I tried with some values and I see that there is no perfect cancellation of the powers of $ π $ and the algebraic factors, so the Area can't be an integer, but I haven't a real demonstration of that.

Edit: these ellipses do exist and are infinitely many! Thanks to @heropup for showing that with a numerical example. I was too focused on finding one with parameters expressible with close form, so if f we restrict on those kind of parameters ([here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) for some examples), is it possible to find one?

Comment: Are you looking for an existence proof, or a specific example? The former seems reasonably obvious (EG by a density/transformation argument), the latter less so.

Comment: Presumably there are infinitely many examples.  Fix the area to be an integer $A$, and then continuously increase the eccentricity while keeping the area unchanged.  The perimeter increases without bound, crossing every integer greater than its initial value.

Comment: @Calvin I would like to find a specific example

Comment: I don't think so because both formulas use $\pi$ which is an irrational number, and the product of a rational number and irrational number is irrational.

Answer (score 3):

For $a = (\pi b)^{-1}$ and $a > b > 0$, then $0 < b < \pi^{-1/2}$.  The area of such an ellipse is unity, and the perimeter is given by
$$P(b) = \frac{4}{\pi b} \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} (1 - (1-\pi^2 b^4) \sin^2 \theta)^{1/2} \, d\theta,$$ which proportional to the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.  Then a plot of $P(b)$ on this interval shows a monotonically decreasing function, with $\lim_{b \to 0^+} P(b) = \infty$ and $P(\pi^{-1/2}) = 2 \sqrt{\pi} \approx 3.54491$.
So there exists $b$ such that $P(b) = 4$.  Newton's method or some other numerical approach (e.g., recursive bisection) yields the value
$$b \approx 0.37334332668583542872022803191598896262977170372452 \ldots$$
for which the perimeter is $4$.  Obviously, a closed form solution is not tractable.  The corresponding value of the semimajor axis is
$$a \approx 0.85259294443381110278147340714140156428522698936557 \ldots.$$

A computer can easily compile a table of such values.

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty dumb thinking there was no solution. Do you think is it possible to prove that no solutions with singular value is possible?

Comment: @user967210 What do you mean by "singular value?"  Please describe this term mathematically.

Comment: here you find some examples https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html